# Не могу вывести окно оповещения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Когда с сокета приходит сообщение, пытаюсь в отдельном потоке вывести окно, если делаю без QThread, окно появляется но аварийно завершается.

С использованием потока, окно даже не появляется, класс WorkThread отрабатывает

```
class WorkThread(Qt.QThread):
threadSignalAlert = Qt.pyqtSignal(str)

def __init__(self, text):
    super(WorkThread, self).__init__()
    self.text = text

def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.threadSignalAlert.emit(self.text)
```

но когда отслеживаю сигнал, метод view_windows не отрабатывает

```
def read_socket(self, sock):
    while True:
        response = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        response = json.loads(response)
        print(response['status'])

        if response['status'] == 'auth':
            if response['status_auth'] == 'success':
                self.hide()

        if response['status'] == 'alert':
            # thread_alert = threading.Thread(target=self.view_windows(str(response['text_alert'])))
            # thread_alert.start()

            self.thrd = WorkThread(text=str(response['text_alert']))
            self.thrd.threadSignalAlert.connect(self.view_windows)
            self.thrd.start()
```

метод view_window:

```
def view_windows(self, text='test'):
    alert_window = PopupWindowClass(text)
    alert_window.show()
    move2RightBottomCorner(alert_window)
```

Comment: в отдельном потоке вывести окно  - нельзя. Покажите минимальный пример не разрывая его по частям. Надо видеть что у вас и где находится и как вызывается.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Lexnom/client_alert - ссылка на проект